# HTACCESS - mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to rename url www.mypage.com/index.php or www.mypage.com/index_cz.php (the same version of index - just in another language) to  www.mypage.com/en or www.mypage.com/cz

I have this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index_cz\.php$ /cz/ [R=301,L]
```

It redirects me to www.mypage.com/en or www.mypage.com/cz but it gimme back NOT FOUND...

Really thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[?/\s]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /en/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index_cz\.php[?/\s]
RewriteRule ^index_cz\.php$ /cz/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/en/?$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^cz/?$ index_cz.php [NC,L]
```